# How to align an image next to a paragraph

Tags: html, css

Something like this...

[img here ]  [ Paragraph here ]

instead of what I have now.

[img here ]

[ Paragraph here ]

## HTML

```
   <p> <div class="polaroid">
     <img src="Me1.jpeg" title="Me" alt="Me" align="left" />
    <p class="polo">That's Me!!!</p>
       </div></p>
    </div>

    <div class="blocker03">
    <p class="description">
 blah blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah
  blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah
    blah   blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah</p>
    </div>
```

### CSS

```
.blocker03 {
 width:470px;
 padding-left:60px;
 margin:0 0 10px 25px;
 font-size:12px;
 display:inline-block;
  }

.polaroid {
postion: relative;
float: right;
border: 3px solid #C6930A;
border-style:dotted;
background: #66594C;
width: 140px;
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px;
text-align: center; 
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222;
-moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222;
-o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
transform: rotate(-5deg);
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

so thats some sloppy code you have there, but check out this jsfiddle for an example using `float`:

http://jsfiddle.net/tH2qc/

And here's something loosly based on your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/zZkpw/

Comment: What more do you expect from a CSS beginner haha.

Comment: haha - we all have to start somehwere.  Read an article on code style.  Having well-indented and organized code is the single best thing you can do to get better.

This might be a good resource: https://github.com/styleguide/css

Comment: Thank You Sir, I will definitely work on it. CSS alignment issues are such a pain for a beginner.

Comment: very true.  MDN (mozilla developer network) also has some great articles on positioning, and the css box model.  You'll be a pro before you know it

Comment: Awesome,shall look into them.

Answer (score 5):

Isn't this all a bit overkill when this will work fine:

```
<p><img src="*[your image]" align="right" valign="middle" vspace="5" hspace="5"/>[your text]</p>
```

Comment: [align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-align) is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div style="float:left;width:800px" id="container">
    <div id="rightContainer" style="float:left;width:100px;">
        <img src="Me1.jpeg" title="Me" alt="Me" align="left" />
        <p class="polo">That's Me!!!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="leftContainer" style="float:right;width:600px;">
        <p class="description"> blah blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will work:

```
.polaroid img, .polaroid p{
   float:left;
   display:inline;
}
```